# Multiple Imputation Exercise

Tags: r, statistics, imputation

I am reviewing multiple imputations methods in R, and I came across a fundamental yet important question. In the script below, what purpose does the number **7** serve in **data[4:10, 3] <- rep(NA, 7)**? Is it telling R to repeat NA seven times?

```
library(mice)
library(Amelia)
library(mi)
library(missForest)
library(Hmisc)
library(mi)

data <- airquality
data[4:10, 3] <- rep(NA, 7) # rows 4 through 10, third column, make it NA
data[1:5, 4] <- NA # rows 1 through 5, fourth column, make it NA
```

Comment: the answer is found in ?rep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
 > rep(NA, 3)
 # [1] NA NA NA
 >rep(NA, 7)
 # [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: I should have tried it myself before asking. Haha. I would like to accept the answer, but the system will only let me after 11 minutes. I will accept your answer soon. Thank you.

Comment: You actually don't need a `rep()` call - R will recycle the `NA` value as many times as it's called for (such as `data[4:10,3] <- NA`)